# how to remove occlusion from face image?

Tags: image-processing, face-recognition, occlusion-culling

Any effective method to remove face occlusion? The effect is like the following figure:

[image]

Any references for that?

Comment: If you know or can mark occlusion manually.. you can try in-painting..

Comment: This is called in-painting and is not limited to faces.

Comment: Thanks! I'll search `in-painting`. But what should I do if I do not know the occlusion. I only the occluded image and original image?

Comment: You could try applying a maximum filter with a small pixel neighbourhood and see if that helps.  Bear in mind that you will lose some of the detail, but it will fill in the holes that are drawn over the face.

Answer (score 0):

If are you dealing with frontal faces, It would be solved simply.

Thus, You can solve that problem using face symmetry feature.

After localizing the eyes and aligning the face, divide the face two parts-left one and right one.

Then scanning line one by one, at first, search the image part where intensity gradient change fast and check whether the part exists in two facial parts equally.

If it's not, then the part is occlusion.